# Is there a shortcut key to split view the file manager on Xubuntu 12.04?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, filemanager

I am wandering to know if an hot key exists to split view the Xubuntu file manager.

It is possible to do it on Ubuntu with `F3`, and it looks like:

[image: manager double]

Comment: Please ask about " ...explain why the key binding `Ctrl + Alt + T` ..." in another question.

Comment: @vasa1 I found here it works with `Win + t`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thunar doesn't have a split view function. So no short-cut either.